# What is 'clean install' vs 'install' in AMD Graphics software?

Tags: gpu, amd-radeon, display-driver, amd-graphics-card

I am trying to install 'Radeon Software' version 'Crimson ReLive Edition 16.12.1'

When installing, I have two options: 'install' vs 'clean install'; what is the difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Install** - regular install without removing old drivers/software.

**Clean Install** - use in a situation like an upgrade from previous version. The clean install will remove the old drivers first and then install the new ones. This is akin to running a program like DDU (Display Driver Uninstaller) so that there will be no driver conflicts with your new drivers. So then it can install your new drivers from a clean slate.